# data not storing in database django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My first issue is data is not going in database.it is not showing any error but not storing as well.
and my second issue is that i am pre-populating the form field with query set in a drop-down but it is showing me the id(primary key) and i want show some other field.how can i do this?

my view

```
def payment(request):
    #form = jobpostForm_first()
    #country_list = Country.objects.all()
    if request.POST:
        form = jobpostForm_detail(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if '_Submit' in request.POST:
              form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = jobpostForm_detail()
        #form.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.all()

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('portal/display.html',{
        'form':form
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my modelform:

```
class jobpostForm_detail(ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = payment_detail
        fields = ('payment_type','country')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(jobpostForm_detail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['country'].queryset = Country.objects.all()
        self.fields['payment_type'].queryset = Payment_types.objects.all()

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'horizontal-form'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-jobpostform'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'


        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit_addcontent', 'Pay'))

        super(jobpostForm_detail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My template:

```
<form method="post" action="/portal/next/post/" class="blueForms" id="id-jobpostform">


    {% csrf_token %}

    {% crispy form %}

    </form>
```

Comment: try `form.full_clean()` before `form.save()`, it should throw errors, if any. Also, since you are sending back the request Context, you dont need to do `c.update`

Comment: ok.. does it redirect to `/thanks` ?

Comment: no it is not redirecting to thanks it redirects me to /portal/next/post/..and even if i remove if form.is_valid():
            if '_Submit' in request.POST: even then it is not saving and redirecting

Comment: just before `request.POST` do a print `request.method` - lets see if request method is actually POST

Comment: not printing anything..this means it is not going even in that chk

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27419/discussion-between-madeeha-ameer-and-karthikr)

Comment: Is your urls.py pointing to the right method?

Comment: yes they are pointing in right direction

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking for `"_Submit"` in your view?

I suggest you read [how to use a form in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view), especially the comments:

```
...
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
...
```

In your case, you just need to call `form.save()` after `form.is_valid()`

Question for you: can you please explain this bit of code in your form class? typo, I suppose?

```
widgets = {

        }),

}
```

Comment: o yes i was using widgets before..forgot to remove..and even when i remove this check(if '_Submit' in request.POST:) still it doesn't store to db.

Comment: clean the code in your OP with the actual code, then. oh yeah, if you have any errors those will do too :)

Comment: cleaned it..can u plz tell me why it is not going to database?

Comment: 1) you still have to remove if '_Submit', which is useless
2) why are you calling super two times in your init? the second call needs to be removed
3) is your form really valid? check with prints/debugs
4) I assume you ran syncdb and your model is properly configured (hint: check it)

Comment: if i remove the super it gives me error ''jobpostForm_detail' object has no attribute 'fields''

Comment: remove the first `super`, not the second one